# Adding The Role Attributes of the Default User in PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL setup with the default user, postgres, for a project. Now, I need to work on another project. For some reason, the DB schema specifies an owner, user2. To work on it, I created the user with a command:

```
create user user2 with password pw2;
```

The command

```
\du
```

yields "role name", "list of roles Attributes", and "Member of" in a table format. And the default user "postgres" has Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, and Bypass RLS  as role attributes. How to add those attributes to the user2?

**Update:**
I have found out to use the command "alter role" to add those attributes. With the change, I am able to run the following command to generate a DB schema:

```
./psql -U user2 mydb < schema.sql
```

That, however, doesn't resolve an issue I have in regarding the owner of sequence, "sequence must be same owner s table it is linked to" for a script,

```
... owned by mydb.a_table.uid
```

. That would be another post.

Comment: 1) Find out the reason there is `user2` owner form whoever created the project. 2) Based on that set the minimum attributes needed. Generally you don't want to setting `superuser` unless absolutely necessary. 3) Read [Create User](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createuser.html), [Alter User](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-alteruser.html) and [Grant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html).

Comment: You shouldn't be using a superuser for your application to begin with.

Comment: Thanks both for your input. I have been in the business for a while and that is my first time seeing a DB table owner specification.